# Trying load data with Ajax in Grails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, grails

I'm trying to load the content registration page using jquery and ajax with the Grails framework.

But when I load the page it shows the expected result, but the menu of the page and also the fields to register the matter are repeated inside the page.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="/Escola/js/Aplicacao/Mensagens.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function carregarMaterias() {
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url:"/Escola/Materia/gerenciar",
                data: {},
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data)
                    $("#cadastrarMaterias").html(data)
                }
            });
        }

    </script>
                         <title>Gerenciar Matérias</title>
```

```
      <h2>Gerenciar Matérias</h2>

    <div class="col-md-6  col-md-offset-3">

        <g:formRemote name="formMateria" url="[controller: 'Materia', action: 'salvarMateria']"
                      onSuccess="cadastarMaterias(data)">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Código da Matéria</label>
                <input required class="form-control" type="text" name="codigoMateria"/>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Matéria</label>
                <input required class="form-control" type="text" name="nome"/>
            </div>


            <div class="text-left">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Salvar</button>
            </div>

            <script>
                $('form').submit(function () {
                    this.reset();
                })
            </script>
            <br/>

            <div id="content"></div>
        </g:formRemote>

        <div class="text-center">
            <h2>Matérias</h2>
        </div>


            <div class="table-responsive" id="cadastrarMaterias">
                <table class="table">

                    <thead>
                    <th>Código da Matéria</th>
                    <th>Nome da Matéria</th>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>

                    <g:each in="${lista}" var="materia">
                        <tr>
                            <td>${materia.codigoMateria}</td>
                            <td>${materia.nome}</td>

                        </tr>
                   </g:each>
               </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

So see the results but the page repeat the same structure twice.

Answer (score 0):

This is because in the bit that you haven't shown:

`controller: Materia Action: salvarMateria`

You are rending a view all over again. The view will enforce the meta tag that renders the main template and hence your issue.

Instead in the salvarMateria action try this:

```
if (request.xhr) {
    render template:'page',model:model
} else {
    render view:'page',model:model
}
```

Now create a _page.gsp and this will then be a case of you having page.gsp and _page.gsp

In the bit of the main page.gsp where it does the iteration for your actual results (if it was not ajax i.e. if not `request.xhr` then load

So all your iterations happen in _page.gsp and it gets called via ajax as well as if non ajax content is then driven by g:render template..
I think you will find an [example here](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-liveform-example).